# Assign an error type to each FluentValidation rule .net c#

Tags: c#, .net, validation, asp.net-core-webapi, fluentvalidation

I am working on fluent validation which will generate custom api response

I am able to add ErrorCode and ErrorMessage in the rules. But I also need to assign a type to each rule.

Below are the rules:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Name).Must(ValidateUniqueName).WithErrorCode("0001").WithMessage("Name should be unique");**type1**
RuleFor(x => x.Address).Must(ValidateValidAddress).WithErrorCode("0002").WithMessage("Address is invalid");**type2**
```

Now I am categorizing these rules into different types because UI has to implement/show the rule's error messages in different ways thats why assigning different types to each rules.
For example rule one is of type type1 and rule 2 is of type type2

Below is the my error class

```
public class ApiError
    {
        public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
        public string ErrorDescription { get; set; }
        public string PropertyName { get; set; }
        public ErrorType ErrorType { get; set; }
    }

    public enum ErrorType
    {
        type1,
        type2
    }
```

Validator code

```
public List<ApiError> Validate<T1, T2>(T1 modelValidator, T2 modelToBeValidated, bool isPropertyNameRequired = false)
            where T1 : IValidator<T2>
            where T2 : class
        {
            List<ApiError> errors = new List<ApiError>();

            var validationResult = modelValidator.Validate(modelToBeValidated);
            foreach (var validationFailure in validationResult.Errors)
            {
                var error = new ApiError
                {
                    ErrorCode = validationFailure.ErrorCode,
                    PropertyName = isPropertyNameRequired ? validationFailure.PropertyName : null
                };
               error.ErrorType = ??
               error.ErrorDescription = validationFailure.ErrorMessage;
               errors.Add(error);
            }

            return errors;
        }
```

Now how can I send types as well along with errorcode and errormessage?
Any help

Comment: I'd support this in the ErrorCodes themselves. Similar to dotnet errorCodes that have "CS12345" or "IDE12345" ... Just prepend an error domain: "T1.0001" , "T2.0002"

Comment: @Fildor: right now i am doing this only. thanks for the confidence that i am not the only one thinking that way.....hhahah just kidding

Comment: That's actually how we do that in our project. We built some convenience shenanigans around this, too. But basically we just use the ErrorCode to determine Error "Domain" or "Type" by a prepended abbreviation and the specific one by number.